# Trying to create a loop to find missing dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bit code that creates missing dates in between my start (J2) and end date (K2). I have a list of around 6000 people with start and end dates and want to repeat the code for each row.

Does anybody know how I can loop this?

```
Sub FindMissingDates()

Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim NextDate As Date
Dim DateOffset As Range
Dim DateIter As Date

FirstDate = Range("J2").Value
LastDate = Range("K2").Value
Set DateOffset = Range("M2")

For DateIter = FirstDate To LastDate
    DateOffset.Value = DateIter
    Set DateOffset = DateOffset.Offset(0, 1)
Next DateIter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your list of names has the start and end dates in columns `J` and `K`, then a quick change to your code like the one below, should do the trick

```
Sub FindMissingDates()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim FirstDate As Date
    Dim LastDate As Date
    Dim NextDate As Date
    Dim DateOffset As Range
    Dim DateIter As Date

    For r = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row '<~~ Loop each row
        FirstDate = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, "J").Value
        LastDate = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, "K").Value
        Set DateOffset = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, "M")

        For DateIter = FirstDate To LastDate
            DateOffset.Value = DateIter
            Set DateOffset = DateOffset.Offset(0, 1)
        Next DateIter
    Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add another For loop.

```
Dim sht As Wokrsheet
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim NextDate As Date
Dim DateOffset As Range
Dim DateIter As Date
Dim i As Integer

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your sheet")
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

FirstDate = Range("J2").Value
LastDate = Range("K2").Value
Set DateOffset = Range("M2")

For i = First row of data To LastRow - 1 
   For DateIter = FirstDate To LastDate
       DateOffset.Value = DateIter
       Set DateOffset = DateOffset.Offset(i, 1)
   Next DateIter
Next i
```

See if this works for you?